# Reclaiming value out of a car needing expensive repair

Tags: tax-deduction, car

I have a car that I purchased for $6k. It drives fine, but needs a new computer, which will cost $2.8k. The diagnosis already cost $400. Given that doing this repair will be 46% of the car value, I am trying to consider ways to reclaim value for the car. The car is valued by [KBB](https://www.kbb.com/toyota/4runner/2001/sr5-sport-utility-4d/?vehicleid=5164&intent=trade-in-sell&mileage=150000&pricetype=private-party&options=6448327|true&condition=good) at $4k. Doing the repair only raises the value (good to excellent) to $4.9k

What options do I have to regain the value of the vehicle? Tax deduction, sale, etc.

Comment: Cars diminish in value through depreciation.  There is no tax deductions for those losses in the US, and likely worldwide.  Your is just more rapid because of the failure of a broken part.   Something similar would happen if your AC quit in most climates.

Comment: Using the car to earn money is about the best way to feel better about vehicle expenses.

Comment: If it drives fine, then why does it need a new computer?

Comment: @GlenYates to pass a smog test

Comment: If you can sell the car for $4k, just sell it then buy another in excellent condition for $4.9k. This will cost $900 instead of $2.8k.

Comment: @aiden.plenert.macdonald, OK, that makes sense, but that is when many people just take it to a state without emissions tests and sell it.

Comment: @GlenYates I never thought of that. Being from CA, I thought emissions testing was standard across the US. I would accept that as an answer if you right it. Maybe if you include some tips on how to sell in another state.